# Error while running react app with next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cmd, next.js, apollo

I'm getting the following console error in my terminal and don't know how to solve it.

I am logging with correct information and don't have any error in my code.

To enter to my aplication I need to log in on form an then enter.  Everything works fine until there but while working on my app and doing some functionalities that it has in my `localhost:/4444` I get the following error and then the app stop running and the local server lose the connection.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide more context. I'd willing to bet you have provided wrong credentials

Comment: @captain-yossarian Please review it again

Comment: Looks like this is a 401 error.  404 error indicates that the request to the API has not been applied since you're not authorized to the API, you can read the `Unauthorized` at the top of massage and also `404` in the content. read more about HTTP response status code in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: @Yahyaparvar you're right, the thing is I am getting my APi data okay in the moment I logging I have no problem with it.